# Importing MEF plugins into DI/IOC container

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

I am trying to use MEF to load plugins into a DI framework. There are multiple types such as:

```
ISocket
IBroadcastSocket
INodeTask
```

Currently I have setup my code this way:

```
[Import]
INodeTask NodeTaskPlugin { get; set; }
```

And trying to import the plugin like so:

```
Injector.Instance.Bind<typeof(INodeTask), NodeTaskPlugin.GetType()>();
```

When trying the above line of code, R# complains that it cannot find the right method:

> Cannot find method group. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Here is the `Bind` declaration that I wish to use:

```
void Bind<TBase, TDerived>() where TDerived : TBase
```

My question is then two fold:

1. How do I solve the above error?
2. Is there a more efficient way of importing plugins into a IoC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the non-generic `Bind` overload of your DI container:

```
Bind(typeof(INodeTask), NodeTaskPlugin.GetType());
```